# How to use, like Google oauth2, to login from web app and access the resource server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to do a POC project. I want to login just like stackoverflow. User just login their google account without having to register first and forget password in the future.

My stack is Angular + Spring boot. Angular or React shouldn't matter here. I have did some research and see how people setup on Google GCP and use it in the webapp.

Ok, now assume I can login in my webapp. I got user's name, picture, etc. How would my Spring boot server auth with the info I got from google?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would get a JWT from Google (or other type of token) that you need to send to your Spring Boot server.

The server should then be configured to verify the token. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html (for JWT).

Basically, add `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` (and `spring-security-oauth2-jose` if JWT) and set the issuer-uri in your applications.(yml | properties)

I think it is `https://accounts.google.com/` for Google. This also assumes that you have created app/oauth2 in google console. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect for details.